# How to check github API is unable to connected to github

Tags: node.js, github, typescript, github-api

Is there any way to check from github api that its unable to connect to github or internet is not connected so when i initialize the api by this :

`GitHubApi = require("github");
        github = new GitHubApi({
            version: "3.0.0"
        });`

it should tell by handled exception that unable to connect to github or internet not connected to allow me to stop using other operations of this API.
as currently i am getting this exception.

```
2//Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:118 [Extension Host] Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.github.com api.github.com:443
    at global.sendError (/Users/fronteed/.vscode/extensions/Shan.code-settings-sync-2.2.3/node_modules/github/lib/index.js:783:19)
    at /Users/fronteed/.vscode/extensions/Shan.code-settings-sync-2.2.3/node_modules/github/lib/index.js:792:29
    at callCallback (/Users/fronteed/.vscode/extensions/Shan.code-settings-sync-2.2.3/node_modules/github/lib/index.js:667:17)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/fronteed/.vscode/extensions/Shan.code-settings-sync-2.2.3/node_modules/github/lib/index.js:739:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:295:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:996:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)(anonymous function) @ //Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:118 //Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:93 Error Logged In Console (Help menu > Toggle Developer Tools). You may open an issue using 'Sync : Open Issue' from advance setting command.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked an exception to check

```
 if (error.code == 500) {
            message = "Sync : Internet Not Connected or Unable to Connect to Github. Exception Logged in Console";
            msgBox = false;
        }
```